# if anidado en SqlServer

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta que dice lo siguiente

```html
si 
       dividir SF.DesctoA/SF.ImporteA si es menor a 1
entonces
       dividir (SF.Descto/(SF.ImporteL+SF.ImporteA)) si es menor a 1
entonces
      dividir (SF.DesctoA+SF.Descto)/(SF.ImporteA+SF.ImporteL)
end

resultado as abono
```

Esta consulta me arroja el error 'Error de división entre cero.'

```html
(case when (SF.DesctoA/SF.ImporteA)< 1 
or (SF.Descto/(SF.ImporteL+SF.ImporteA))< 1 
then ((SF.DesctoA+SF.Descto)/(SF.ImporteA+SF.ImporteL)) 
else '0' end) as Abono
```

Finalmente lo he resuelto asi

```html
sum (CASE SF.DesctoA/NULLIF(SF.ImporteA,0)
 WHEN 0 THEN (SF.Descto/NULLIF((SF.ImporteL+SF.ImporteA),0))
       WHEN 0 THEN ((SF.DesctoA+SF.Descto)/NULLIF((SF.ImporteA+SF.ImporteL),0))
   ELSE 0
   END)*100 AS '%Abono'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes contralar la división por 0. De existir un error de este tipo, retornara NULL entre la división (*confirma si esta correcta la evaluación en el CASE*).

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SF.DesctoA/NULLIF(SF.ImporteA,0) < 1 OR (SF.Descto/NULLIF((SF.ImporteL+SF.ImporteA),0)) 
        THEN ((SF.DesctoA+SF.Descto)/NULLIF((SF.ImporteA+SF.ImporteL),0))
    ELSE 0
    END AS Abono
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta pero me lanza este error ''Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'ELSE'.

Comment: Me había faltado cerrar un paréntesis (edite la respuesta)

Comment: Muy amable pero ahora me lanza esto 'Se especificó una expresión no booleana en un contexto donde se esperaba una condición, cerca de 'THEN'.' despues del OR

Comment: @Huntzberger edite la pregunta agregando las columnas y los tipos de datos de cada columna. Por ejemplo ¿qué tipo de dato tiene la columna `SF.DesctoA`? = toda esta información tiene que ir en la pregunta.